# Wierd AngularJS error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am rather new to AngularJS programming and was working on a sample application. I came across a problem while returning an object from a service. Consider following code in my custom service:

```
this.getCompanyInfo = function(companyID)
{
    console.log( companyID );
    angular.forEach( companyInfo, function( coInf ) {
       if( coInf.companyID == companyID )
       {
           console.log(coInf);
           return coInf;
       }
   })
}
```

in this code, `companyInfo` is an array containing information about companies, each company is represented by an object. the second `console.log` is showing this:

```
Object {companyID: "CHCL", companyName: "Chilime Hydropower", stockPriceTrend: Array[4]}
```

in my controller, I have this:

```
$scope.companyInfo = dataServices.getCompanyInfo( $routeParams.companyID);
console.log($scope.companyInfo);
```

but here, `console.log` says 'undefined'.

I don't know what wrong I have been doing, any help will be highly appreciated!

Regards.

Comment: You should use `===` instead of `==` http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/

Comment: @JadeSync can you please accept one of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just returning from the iterator function argument of the forEach (not from `getCompanyInfo`) which will still go on. But you need to return the actual value from your `getCompanyInfo` function. You can just use a simple for loop and return the value once you find a match.

```
this.getCompanyInfo = function(companyID)
{
    var cInfo, i, l;
    for(i=0,l=companyInfo.length; i<l;i++){
        if((cInfo = companyInfo[i]).companyID === companyID ){
          return cInfo ;
       }
    }

}
```

Returning from the iterator function does not break the looping using `angular.forEach`. Loop will still go on.

Comment: thanks dude you're awesome and apparently i still suck :( 
issue resolved :)

Comment: @JadeSync You are welcome. Also worth noting that if you don't want the loop to continue once you find a match, ForEach is not going to help.. It will still go on and on till the end which you don't need to do in your case...

Answer (score 1):

change function to

```
this.getCompanyInfo = function(companyID)
{
   var coInfo;
    console.log( companyID );
    angular.forEach( companyInfo, function( coInf ) {
       if( coInf.companyID == companyID )
       {
           console.log(coInf);
           coInfo = coInf;
       }
   })

   return coInfo;

}
```

you are not returning value from function but from forEach and that will not return the value from the function.

it has nothing to do with angular, btw.

**EDIT**

also you can use libraries like lodash/underscore for search/filter functionalities